# How can one manage big changes with 3 connected branches, many incoming changes and one person creating features in Git?

Tags: git, merge, branch

#### My situation:

- I have a relatively big Git `repo` with incoming changes from other ~5 developers on constant basis (not fixed terms).
- There is a `master` branch, then the checked out `feature-1` from `master` and then the checked out branch `feature-2` from `feature-1`.

```
-----master-----> (new commits from others)
           \
            feature-1
                     \
                      feature-2-----> (new commits from me)
```

- My changes will affect the whole `repo` including tests. It will take me 2-4 weeks. The changes are not functionality based but rather just handling exceptions + modifying tests.

#### The problem:

1. When I have my changes done on the code from 2-4 weeks ago and I pull new changes from `master` in 2-4 weeks, there are not only merge conflicts, but also new functionalities that might have not been covered. This means I have to start somewhat from scratch and go through the whole `repo` again to make sure my changes cover all that's needed up to date.

#### What I look for

I look for an efficient way to manage such delivery of changes to `master` from `feature-2`. One thing to consider, I have to pull the changes from master to `feature-2` (How do I do it?) and submit changes to `master` (through merge requests) from `feature-2`.

Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

If both the feature branches are local, keep rebasing your feature 1 branch from time to time (Everyday, just as a morning ritual)